# bitbucket needs ip range used by cloud source repository for whitelisting purpose

Tags: google-cloud-source-repos

We are implementing ip whitelisting inside bitbucket. We need to add ip address range of cloud source repository as we are using mirroring to update the CSR.

got 35.185.0.0/16 from bard; but its not working. Is there an alternate way to achieve ip whitelisting?

Comment: Have you checked this [list of ipranges](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json) based on this [Github link](https://github.com/femueller/cloud-ip-ranges)?

Comment: Yes I tried that link as well. But that link has all the resources IP ranges. I need only cloud source repository IP range..

Comment: As of the moment, there's no specific IP range for a specific GCP service, i.e., Cloud Source Repositories. You may check this similar [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/111181099) previously filed for this option to be available in the future however it doesn't have a specific ETA. Hope this helps.